# Can I use a string in-line with a dynamic?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net

I have the following code to collect a value from a json object using dynamic.

`var valueOne = jsonObj.features[0].properties.POLYGON_NM.ToString();`

I would like to grab other values as well, without manually typing every option.

`var valueTwo = jsonObj.features[0].properties.[TEXTBOX_VALUE].ToString();`

Is this possible using Dynamics?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What do you mean by *I would like to grab other values as well, without manually typing every option.*?  Can you clarify please?

Comment: @dbc I'm trying to build a psudo compiler giving my user the ability to pull a value from the JSON and insert it into a SQL insert statement. Thus they'll need access to any value in the json. However when dynamically typed I'm unable to insert the string as a dynamic class.

Comment: I mean, what specifically are you trying to do here, that you are stuck on?  Do you mean, *How can I loop through all the property names and values of a JSON object*?

Comment: @dbc In a sense I want to access a property name and value by name (from a string). Without looping through. I access this method many hundreds of thousands of times and performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JObject for this senario.

```
        JObject j = JObject.Parse("your json");
        var valueTwo = j["TEXTBOX_VALUE"];
```